# Disable Start Date in Material Date Range Picker

Tags: angular, angular-material

Problem: I need to conditionally disable the editing of the Start Date.

Following the documentation [Datepicker | angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

In particular cases, I require that the start date should be uneditable. If its passed in as Sept 15, 2020, then it needs to stay that way. However, when the calendar is opened, a user can just simply click a few times and the start date will be changed.

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my solution will be useful for you. I used a variave to save the start date and a function that observes the changes in the formcontrol.

```
 changeStartDate(){
  this.formEditOffer.get('dataRange').get('start').valueChanges.subscribe(data=> {
    if(data !== this.startDate){
      this.formEditOffer.get('dataRange').get('start').patchValue(this.startDate)
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: I did end up using this type of solution in a couple places. thx. But as of this moment, I just used an ngIf to flip between the usage of the Range Picker and just a Date picker when it cant be avoided. Not ideal, but yea. Thx

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs, you can disable the date selection using the `disabled` property

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Completely disabled</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp1" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp1></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

with this you should be able to dynamically se the `disabled` property based on whatever condition you need. i.e.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp1" [disabled]="ENTER YOUR CRITERIA HERE">
```

with this you should be able to disable the input based on your business rules

Comment: This appears to disable the input text section, but as soon as the calendar is opened, simply clicking a date will set the disabled input to the new value